# boost::range how to insert elements in a map with input piped

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I want to use boost:range utilities to transform a vector and put the original elements as keys and transformed elements as values in a std::map. I came up with something like below. As it is evident, I am missing the way we can actually insert elements in the last step. Could you please help me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/copy.hpp>

const std::vector<int> vec = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

void doSomething(int i)
{
    // Do Something
}

/** Map integers to the alphabet: 0->a, 1->b, ... */
std::string alphabetize(int i) 
{
    return std::string(1, 'a' + i);
}

int main() 
{
     std::map<std::string, int > myMap; 
     boost::copy(vec | boost::adaptors::transformed(alphabetize), std::inserter(myMap, myMap.end()));
}
```

To extend it further how can I use for_each to call a function for all elements like this

```
 boost::range::for_each(myMap | boost::adaptors::map_value, doSomething);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make function, that returns pair, not string.

```
std::pair<std::string, int> alphabetize(int i) 
{
    return std::make_pair(std::string(1, 'a' + i), i);
}
```

Comment: just `return { std::string(1, 'a' + i), i };` also works

Comment: @TemplateRex Well, ye. But there is no c++11 in code, so, I modify function without C++11.

Comment: Brilliant, did not occur to me. I was just trying to plumb a range algorithm

Comment: To extend it further how can I use for_each to call a function for all elements like this